# How in GUI to show the text from the file which changes?

Tags: autoit

In the file `1.txt` in the first line there is an inscription, and it changes over time. In the GUI, it should also be changed. How to make it not flicker?

```
Local $Form1 = GUICreate('Form1', 261, 200, 192, 124)
$10 = FileReadLine ( "1.txt",  1);
GUISetState()
Local $spic = $10, $Pic1
While 1
    $Pic1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel($10, 10, 70, 235, 50)
    Switch FileExists($spic)
        Case 0
            If $Pic1 Then
                GUICtrlDelete($Pic1)
                $Pic1 = 0
            EndIf
        Case 1
            If Not $Pic1 Then $Pic1 = GUICtrlCreatePic($spic, 16, 24, 212, 124)
    EndSwitch
    Sleep(1)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

; Create the Gui.
$Form1 = GUICreate('Form1', 261, 200, 192, 124)
$iLabel = GUICtrlCreateLabel('', 10, 10, 235, 50)
$iPic = GUICtrlCreatePic('', 16, 34, 212, 124)
GUISetState()

; Hide picture control if no file [True|False].
$bHideImage = FileExists('default.jpg') ? False : True

; Updates in the loop to recognize change.
$sSavedFilename = ''

; Set time to reset image etc.
$iTimeReset = 1000
$hTimeStamp = TimerInit()

While 1
    ; Get Gui messages.
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GUIDelete()
            Exit
    EndSwitch

    ; Check if time needs reset.
    If TimerDiff($hTimeStamp) > $iTimeReset Then
        $hTimeStamp = TimerInit()
    Else
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

    ; Read 1st line of a file.
    $sReadFilename = FileReadLine ('1.txt', 1)

    ; If the saved line is different to read line.
    If $sSavedFilename <> $sReadFilename Then
        GUICtrlSetData($iLabel, $sReadFilename)

        Switch FileExists($sReadFilename)
            Case 0
                If $bHideImage Then
                    GUICtrlSetState($iPic, $GUI_HIDE)
                Else
                    ; Display a default (blank?) image.
                    GUICtrlSetImage($iPic, 'default.jpg')
                EndIf

            Case 1
                If $bHideImage Then
                    GUICtrlSetState($iPic, $GUI_SHOW)
                EndIf

                ; Display the new image.
                GUICtrlSetImage($iPic, $sReadFilename)
        EndSwitch

        ; Save the current filename.
        $sSavedFilename = $sReadFilename
    EndIf
WEnd
```

[Sleep](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Sleep.htm) is accurate to approximately
10 milliseconds, which is of so little time to update a control, thus
you get the flicker.

Update of labels which do not occur on an event like a button click,
can be handled using a timer.

If you use a message loop Gui, then you get the Gui messages with using
[GuiGetMsg](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUIGetMsg.htm). After the messages, you can check a time stamp to know if
the time difference is larger than the time reset value which is currently
set as `1000` milliseconds. If larger, timer is reset and the code below
is executed, else will continue the loop from the top.

The filename read from the text file is saved to `$sSavedFilename`.
Updating of controls is only done when the read filename is different. If
the filename read does not exist, then display a default (blank?) image.
I sometimes choose a default image else an empty filename instead can
cause control sizing issues with the next image change. The control could
be instead be hidden, if no image to show. `$bHideImage` current decides
to use the file `default.jpg` if exist, else to hides the control.

This code updates the created controls instead of deleting and recreating them.

- Update [GUICtrlCreateLabel](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreateLabel.htm) text with [GUICtrlSetData](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetData.htm).
- Update [GUICtrlCreatePic](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreatePic.htm) image with [GUICtrlSetImage](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetImage.htm).